# Can I add to a method without editing the class method itself?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to run a function of my own when a class method runs. The only way I know of is to edit the class's method and make it run my function when it's called. Is there no way I can simply make it run my function whenever the class method runs without editing it?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to do something whenever a class's method runs, but I don't want to edit the class itself and preferably (if possible) want to have my code in a seperate file.

Comment: No it's not possible. You have to edit the class. Of course you can still have almost all your code in a separate file. But three has to be some change to the class whose behaviour you are trying to modify.

Comment: Would inheriting the class, overwriting the method and calling the parent class method implementation be an option? I.e. the key would be using the `::`.

Comment: If you cannot do somthing like a proxy pattern not in C++ AFAIK

Comment: @olawrdhalpme If you can't edit the class implementation at compile-time, and the class method in question is not `virtual`, then your only option is to *detour* the class method at runtime, by manually patching the method's compiled code to jump to another function in memory, and then that function can jump back when finished. There are plenty of detouring libraries available online if you look around.

Comment: @Yunnosch what you suggest would work only if the method in question is `virtual`

Comment: Why don't you want to edit the class itself? (Sure, you could work around this by editing potentially every other file in your project, but that seems like the less desirable option.)

Answer (score 0):

A simple and idiomatic way to do this is using a subclass:

```
// the original class
class A {
    int foo() { return 123; }
}

// the class you'll use
class B : public A {
    int foo() {
        function_of_my_own();
        return A::foo();
    }
}
```

But this will only work if you actually work with `B`s. If you have code taking `A&`'s, and invoking their `foo()` method, you won't get the subclass behavior. For that case you'll need to ensure the base class method is marked virtual:

```
class A {
    virtual int foo() { return 123; }
}

// the class you'll use
class B : public A {
    int foo() override {
        function_of_my_own();
        return A::foo();
    }
}
```

And this way, any function using references or pointers to `A`, and receiving a `B`, will have the `B::foo()` behavior, i.e. will call your extra function.

For more on virtual methods in C++, read the [cppreference page about them](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

There are other - mostly more complicated - approaches which may be more or less relevant to your use case.